# Drupal 7 Views: Combine exposed filter with contextual filter?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter, drupal-contextual-filters

Is there a way to make an exposed filter and contextual filter play nice with each other? I have the title field set as my exposed filter and then I also have a contextual filter in glossary mode. When I do a search with my exposed filter it works normally until I click on one of the letters for my contextual glossary.. then I get no results.

For example when I first come to my page it shows me that there are 35 records for the letter P. if I do a search for the word Christmas I get some results on the page but the number of records for the letter P still says 35. When I click on the letter P I get 0 results because the view is still being filtered by the word Christmas.

Is there anyway to make these two things play nicely with each other to get some results that make a little more sense? It would be nice if I clicked on a glossary letter than the exposed title filter would be reset.

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable the [filter_harmonizer](https://drupal.org/project/filter_harmonizer) module (Actually this module was publish after the question date)
2. (optionally) Disable AJAX for the views and set the contextual filter:

   - "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL -> Display all results for the specified field" because by default it shows titles beginning with letter "a" in the first load.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with changing the 'AND' for your filters to 'OR'
By default, if you check the added filters, they are added with 'AND' condition. So, each time you filter the result, its 'AND'ed with previous query.

Regards.